# How to truncate text and make left side of text show in a textField

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `textfield` (see image) that when a user selects an address it is copied into the `textfield`. The issue is, even when the `textfield` loses focus, it is that you cannot see the beginning of the text. In this example, the street number is to the left and cut off. I want the `textfield`, when losing focus or when text is set programmatically, to show the far left side of the text, not the right side. I am guessing the cursor is at the end. But when losing focus there is no cursor, a `textfield` below has focus.

[image]

I am using AutoComplete package. But here is the code.

```
library auto_complete_text_view;

import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

typedef void OnTapCallback(String value);

class AutoCompleteTextView extends StatefulWidget
    with AutoCompleteTextInterface {
  final double maxHeight;
  final TextEditingController controller;

  //AutoCompleteTextField properties
  final tfCursorColor;
  final tfCursorWidth;
  final tfStyle;
  final tfTextDecoration;
  final tfTextAlign;
  //Suggestiondrop Down properties
  final suggestionStyle;
  final suggestionTextAlign;
  final onTapCallback;
  final Function getSuggestionsMethod;
  final Function focusGained;
  final Function focusLost;
  final int suggestionsApiFetchDelay;
  final Function onValueChanged;

  AutoCompleteTextView(
      {@required this.controller,
      this.onTapCallback,
      this.maxHeight = 0,
      this.tfCursorColor = Colors.white,
      this.tfCursorWidth = 2.0,
      this.tfStyle = const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      this.tfTextDecoration = const InputDecoration(),
      this.tfTextAlign = TextAlign.left,
      this.suggestionStyle = const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      this.suggestionTextAlign = TextAlign.left,
      @required this.getSuggestionsMethod,
      this.focusGained,
      this.suggestionsApiFetchDelay = 0,
      this.focusLost,
      this.onValueChanged});
  @override
  _AutoCompleteTextViewState createState() => _AutoCompleteTextViewState();

  //This funciton is called when a user clicks on a suggestion
  @override
  void onTappedSuggestion(String suggestion) {
    onTapCallback(suggestion);
  }
}

class _AutoCompleteTextViewState extends State<AutoCompleteTextView> {
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  OverlayEntry _overlayEntry;
  LayerLink _layerLink = LayerLink();
  final suggestionsStreamController = new BehaviorSubject<List<String>>();
  List<String> suggestionShowList = List<String>();
  Timer _debounce;
  bool isSearching = true;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
        this._overlayEntry = this._createOverlayEntry();
        Overlay.of(context).insert(this._overlayEntry);
        (widget.focusGained != null) ? widget.focusGained() : () {};
      } else {
        this._overlayEntry.remove();
        (widget.focusLost != null) ? widget.focusLost() : () {};
      }
    });
    widget.controller.addListener(_onSearchChanged);
  }

  _onSearchChanged() {
    if (_debounce?.isActive ?? false) _debounce.cancel();
    _debounce =
        Timer(Duration(milliseconds: widget.suggestionsApiFetchDelay), () {
      if (isSearching == true) {
        _getSuggestions(widget.controller.text);
      }
    });
  }

  _getSuggestions(String data) async {
    if (data.length > 0 && data != null) {
      List<String> list = await widget.getSuggestionsMethod(data);
      suggestionsStreamController.sink.add(list);
    }
  }

  OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry() {
    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
    var size = renderBox.size;
    return OverlayEntry(
        builder: (context) => Positioned(
              width: size.width,
              child: CompositedTransformFollower(
                link: this._layerLink,
                showWhenUnlinked: false,
                offset: Offset(0.0, size.height + 5.0),
                child: Material(
                  elevation: 4.0,
                  child: StreamBuilder<Object>(
                      stream: suggestionsStreamController.stream,
                      builder: (context, suggestionData) {
                        if (suggestionData.hasData &&
                            widget.controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
                          suggestionShowList = suggestionData.data;
                          return ConstrainedBox(
                            constraints: new BoxConstraints(
                              maxHeight: 0,
                            ),
                            child: ListView.builder(
                                controller: scrollController,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: suggestionShowList.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return ListTile(
                                    title: Text(
                                      suggestionShowList[index],
                                      style: widget.suggestionStyle,
                                      textAlign: widget.suggestionTextAlign,
                                    ),
                                    onTap: () {
                                      isSearching = false;
                                      widget.controller.text =
                                          suggestionShowList[index];
                                      suggestionsStreamController.sink.add([]);
                                      widget.onTappedSuggestion(
                                          widget.controller.text);
                                    },
                                  );
                                }),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return Container();
                        }
                      }),
                ),
              ),
            ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CompositedTransformTarget(
      link: this._layerLink,
      child: TextField(
        controller: widget.controller,
        decoration: widget.tfTextDecoration,
        style: widget.tfStyle,
        cursorColor: widget.tfCursorColor,
        cursorWidth: widget.tfCursorWidth,
        textAlign: widget.tfTextAlign,
        focusNode: this._focusNode,
        onChanged: (text) {
          if (text.trim().isNotEmpty) {
            (widget.onValueChanged != null)
                ? widget.onValueChanged(text)
                : () {};
            isSearching = true;
            scrollController.animateTo(
              0.0,
              curve: Curves.easeOut,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            );
          } else {
            isSearching = false;
            suggestionsStreamController.sink.add([]);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    suggestionsStreamController.close();
    scrollController.dispose();
    widget.controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

abstract class AutoCompleteTextInterface {
  void onTappedSuggestion(String suggestion);
}
```

Comment: Can you post `TextField` code for the mentioned image.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `ScrollController` we can make the text on the far left side visible.

1. Create and initialize `final scrollController = ScrollController();`.
2. Create a method for showing left side text contents, method contains `scrollController.jumpTo(0.0);`.
3. In the `TextField` add `scrollController:` property and set its value to `scrollController` from step 1.
4. In the `TextField` add `onEditingComplete:` property and set its value to method created in step 2.

Made a Small Code sample for the above mentioned points: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/datgrp4b)

**Note:**

1. This code **does not** move the cursor. It only makes the left side visible.
2. This code relies on the `onEditingComplete` callback, in different situations you may need to use another callback.